# How can I start with Input/Output programming with assembly in an OS independent environment?

Tags: assembly, input

After learning assembly language I am trying to put challenges. One of them is to learn Input/Ouput programming with it. The bad part is that I can't find a source that teaches how to approach such problem and most of the articles I found in Google have something similar to "These instructions are quite complicated to use, so we usually use the operating system to do I/O for us instead" but now I am working outside the operating system using a very simple 512 boot loader i wrote myself (i.e. Running no os).

Would you please suggest some sources that can teach such stuff ?

Comment: What do you mean by "but now I am working outside the operating system" ? Since assembly language is closest machine language, its I/O instruction will always be specific to OS. For ex, it was interrupts in DOS and now its, API in Win32.

Comment: @Madhur: Software interrupts are still used in practically every OS for the system call interface.

Comment: @thkala: In terms of assembly programming, I/O has moved from interrupts to API. That was my point.

Comment: @AssemblyGuy: are you trying to drive the hardware directly? If you are, at least use the BIOS routinges. Otherwise you will have to read-up on every little piece of hardware in your computer, from the keyboard controller to the graphics adapter. It's a very lengthy process.

Comment: @Madhur: Are you talking about calling system library routines from assembly code ?

Comment: @thkala: Yes, I am talking about calling I/O routines for DOS and Windows in assembly.

Comment: What is the target platform?  Something embedded?  An x86 pc?  And are you interested in BIOS calls or talking to hardware directly, and what hardware GPIO, serial, video, other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look, High level assembly by Randall Hyde
http://homepage.mac.com/randyhyde/webster.cs.ucr.edu/HighLevelAsm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It you are "outside the operating system" that means there is no operating system, or it is a loose one (probably called an "executive") which allows programs to directly access i/o devices.  The latter is especially troublesome:  what happens if two programs both read from the same serial line at the same time?

I suggest starting with writing device drivers for a good and reasonably gentle introduction.  Virtually all device drivers are written in C or C++ now, and studying how they interact with device interrupts and control registers is the first hurdle you'll have in understanding how to program that in assembly.  See [this](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux).

If you have a small dedicated device, like an embedded controller where an operating system isn't a foregone conclusion, you have a choice of looking at vendor examples, or reading documentation written by hardware engineers—a major challenge for several reasons, the least of which is a significantly different mindset than software engineers.  Either way, there is quite a learning curve just to understand the context of many concepts, let alone writing the first useful line of code.